# How do I enable mod_rewrite on Apache??? It looks like it's enabled but it's not working

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Sorry I don't know what I'm doing and I need your help. I have an htaccess file that does some url rewriting but its not working on the server. I don't think mod_rewrite is enabled. but it's not commented out, and phpinfo() says that it is one of the enabled modules.

I don't know what to do. Please help!

from my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Update: I changed this line from none to all in http.conf:

```
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
    AllowOverride All
```

I saved it. Tried to restart apache (by doing what my IT guy said: /sbin/service httpd restart), but apache couldn't restart saying:

```
Stopping httpd: [FAILED]
Starting httpd: [FAILED]
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
```

Now I can't roll back cuz I get the same message...what is wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable mod_rewrite functionality in the particular area where you want it, either in the Location, VirtualHost or .htaccess. You can do this with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html
```

You can see what the module is doing by turning on logging using the RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel options:

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache/rewrite.log" 
RewriteLogLevel 2
```

The log level goes up to 9, but the documentation warns against going beyond 2 for production. I'd recommend turning it off completely once you've finished debugging.

You can find more information in the [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Having seen your usage, it appears that you're trying to send items that don't exist to index.php. You could do something similar without using mod_rewrite:

```
 ErrorDocument 404 http://this.server/path/index.php
```

This would redirect the user back to the index.php and will require you to hardcode the location, which may not be ideal.

Alternatively, I'd recommend inverting the meaning of your conditions and remove the first RewriteRule. "If the request isn't a file and isn't a link and isn't a directory, then redirect to index.php". This will make your rules simpler. You can also lose the [NC] flag from your RewriteRules, as it won't have any effect.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond ! %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteCond ! %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteCond ! %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
```

(I haven't checked that this works)

Comment: I already tried something like RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html and it didn't render new stuff. It completely ignored the rewrite rule

Comment: What did the rewrite log file say? If there's nothing in the log file, then it's not hitting that config section.

Comment: Apparently I don't have appropriate permissions to turn on logging and view the logs. I guess I'm going to have to wait for someone with permission to get it working.

Comment: ok, now I have root access, but I can't restart apache. I get Starting httpd: [FAILED]
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

Comment: Looks like apache didn't stop properly and is still running. Stop it normally, check to see if there are any processes still running and kill them. Then start apache again

Comment: I got it working. I guess there was something wrong with the way I was trying to restart Apache via ssh. Once I got physical access to the server, it was really easy.

Comment: By the way...my original .htaccess file is the Zend Framework "recommended" approach. I don't know what any of it means, but I know it gets the job done.

Comment: Also, I tried your suggestion about the htaccess file and it didn't work. It gave me an error. Thanks anyway though

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't sure if it would work exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Apache Server?